# Clean up php array via alphabetical keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am extracting data from an xls document which returns as an array. The array keys however is not numeric, but resembles the cell column alphabetical digit. So effectively I have an array like this:

```
  // Example array:
  $array = array(
        [0] => array(
              "A" => "Name",
              "B" => "Surname",
              "C" => "",
              "D" => "Telephone"
        ),
        [1] => array(
              "A" => "Name",
              "B" => "Surname",
              "C" => "",
              "D" => "Telephone"
        ),
        [2] => array(
              "A" => "",
              "B" => "",
              "C" => "",
              "D" => ""
        )
  );
```

Now the problem with the returned array is it does not filter the array at all, and I may have rows and rows of empty values in the rows.

I need a way to either clean up the array completely so remove empty rows and digits, but this may give me some issues with array consistancy later.

What I am looking for is a function which can chop rows in an array by a alphebitical digit. So effectively something like array_chop($array","C"); which would then effectively unset all the remainder rows key and value pairs from D onwards.

Is this possible? Is there a php function already I can use? I am sorry that I cannot provide sample code but I have no idea where to start. The array is substancially large, so I am looking for a memory efficient solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Plain old `foreach` is what you need

Comment: zerkms, I was worried this would be the only way. The issue is that the array has around 6000 rows, so a foreach will take forever.

Comment: why would you chop at C when D still contains Telephone?

Comment: @Mauritz 6000 rows is nothing for modern computers, and a built-in function would also just loop over it.

Comment: @Mauritz Swanepoel: "around 6000 rows, so a foreach will take forever" --- the difference between a real programmer and a fortune-teller is that the first ones operate with facts.

Comment: @Gordon, the problem is that when importing the data I now have keys up to AK or something, where effectively there is only 4 actual values per row in the array. If I can somewhat hard chop the remainder of the array after the 5th row, I know I get all of the content and chop down well over 50% of the array.

Comment: The 1st, 2nd and 3rd optimisation rules: first measure (profile), then optimize

Comment: well let me get to work then

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel i still dont understand why you would want to chop the array instead of just array_filter it. chopping will potentially make you lose data (Telephone when chopped at C). Filtering will make you "lose" the empty elements. Also, cant you filter in the export already?

Comment: @Gordon: If I use array_filter() would it not say for example in my array above remove $array[0]['C'] as well? So effectively leave me with 3 elements instead of 4? If I chop it I kind of have control what content will always be presented and correctly indexed. I would rather have an empty value for "C" than remove the entire value pair.

Comment: @Gordon: Also, I am really asking if it would do that, I am not too familiar with array_filter so not sure if that is how it works?

Comment: @Mauritz Swanepoel: how about http://php.net/array_filter ? It's a good idea to try *before* you ask. Especially in a such practical, not theoretical at all cases

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel yes, it would remove [0]['C']. Is the association from Letter to Data important? It would help if you could explain what the purpose of that array will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy only a small first portion of the column, this must be efficient:

```
<?php
$array = array(
      0 => array(
            "A" => "Name",
            "B" => "Surname",
            "C" => "",
            "D" => "Telephone"
            ),
      1 => array(
            "A" => "Name",
            "B" => "Surname",
            "C" => "",
            "D" => "Telephone"
            ),
      2 => array(
            "A" => "",
            "B" => "",
            "C" => "",
            "D" => ""
            )
      );

$last_column = 1;

$n = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
      $copy = array();
      $j = 0;
      foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value)
      {
            if ($j <= $last_column)
            {
                  $copy[$key] = $value;
                 ++$j;
            }
            else
            {
                  $array[$i] = $copy;
                  break;
            }
      }
}

var_dump($array);
```

This leaves only name and surname in the matrix:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    string(4) "Name"
    ["B"]=>
    string(7) "Surname"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    string(4) "Name"
    ["B"]=>
    string(7) "Surname"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["B"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```